# Exclude Dependency Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I have a problem of conflicting dependencies.

The two jars are:

- `net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.4.1`
- `com.connectifier.xero:client:0.13`

Which both seem to be loading different versions of the same dependency:
`org.bouncycastle`.

I can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try.

Have been trying something like this:

```
configure(globalModule) {

dependencies {
    compile('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.4.1')
    compile('com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7') {
       exclude group: 'org.bouncycastle'
    }
    compile('com.connectifier.xero:client:0.13') {
       exclude group: 'org.bouncycastle'
    }
}
```

The error I keep getting is:

> SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

The app will run fine if I do not import JasperReports, but I definitely need this.

Answer (score 5):

I have resolved it!   The normal method of exclude in gradle was not working and the workaround was as follows:

```
configure(globalModule) {
    dependencies {
        compile('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.4.1')
        compile('com.connectifier.xero:client:0.13')    
        compile('com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7')    
    }   

    configurations {
        compile {
            exclude group: 'org.bouncycastle'
            exclude module: 'bcprov-jdk14'
        }
    }
    task enhance(type: CubaEnhancing)   

}
```